# Convert Dictionary to JSON specific format

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have the below dictionary

```
{'A': ['ABC', 'DEF'],
 'B': ['GHI','JKL', 'MNO']
}
```

And need to transform it to the below json format

```
{
    "type": "A",
    "keys": [
        "ABC",
        "DEF"
            ]
}
{
    "type": "B",
    "keys": [
        "GHI",
        "JKL",
        "MNO",
        "PQR"
            ]
}
```

]

I've tried  the below but it is not working as I want

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as json_file:
  json.dump(final, json_file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the dictionary yourself:

```
result = [
  {"type": Type, "keys": keys}
  for Type, keys in original_dict.items()
]
```

Or, alternatively:

```
>>> list(map(lambda pair: dict(zip(["type", "keys"], pair)), original_dict.items()))
[{'type': 'A', 'keys': ['ABC', 'DEF']}, {'type': 'B', 'keys': ['GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO']}]
```

Then `dump` `result` to the file.